# TypeScript with knockout.js and ORM

Tags: node.js, knockout.js, orm, typescript, node-orm2

I would like to use TypeScript wiht Knockout.js 3 and ORM. On the [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) side I found different knockout.js modules, but I am not sure whether I need all of them to run knockout.js 3?

- knockout.deferred.updates
- knockout.editables
- knockout.es5
- knockout.kogrid
- knockout.mapper
- knockout.mapping
- knockout.postbox
- knockout.projections
- knockout.rx
- knockout.validation
- knockout.viewmodel
- knockout

For ORM and TypeScript I found [node-orm2](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2/tree/master/lib/TypeScript). Is it the best way to go or there a better solutions for ORM and TypeScript?

Comment: To run knockout you only need `knockout` the other modules are just plugins which are optional.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need anything other than knockout to use knockout in nodejs.

So type in:

```
npm install knockout
```